# AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am inheriting 'account.partner.ledger' module. When we select the customer we will be able to print the report of the customer's ledger. In the partner ledger menu I want to make 'include Initial Balances' checkbox checked by default if the filter is by date/period.I tried to override the method by my custom module but I am unable to solve the error which I am getting.

Code,

```
@api.multi
def onchange_filter(self,filter='filter_no', fiscalyear_id=False):
    res = super(account_partner_ledger, self).onchange_filter(filter=filter, fiscalyear_id=fiscalyear_id)
    if filter in ['filter_no', 'unreconciled']:
        if filter == 'unreconciled':
            res['value'].update({'fiscalyear_id': False})
        res['value'].update({'initial_balance': False, 'period_from': False, 'period_to': False, 'date_from': False ,'date_to': False})

    if filter in ['filter_date','filter_period']:
        res['value'].update({'initial_balance': True, 'period_from': True, 'period_to': True, 'date_from': True ,'date_to': True})
    return res
```

Error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zendynamix\odooGit\odoo8\openerp\http.py", line 544, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "C:\Users\zendynamix\odooGit\odoo8\openerp\http.py", line 581, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "C:\Users\zendynamix\odooGit\odoo8\openerp\http.py", line 317, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zendynamix\odooGit\odoo8\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zendynamix\odooGit\odoo8\openerp\http.py", line 314, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\zendynamix\odooGit\odoo8\openerp\http.py", line 810, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\zendynamix\odooGit\odoo8\openerp\http.py", line 410, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\zendynamix\odooGit\odoo8\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 944, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zendynamix\odooGit\odoo8\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zendynamix\odooGit\odoo8\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zendynamix\odooGit\odoo8\openerp\api.py", line 399, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zendynamix\odooGit\odoo8\openerp\models.py", line 5985, in onchange
    record._onchange_eval(name, field_onchange[name], result)
  File "C:\Users\zendynamix\odooGit\odoo8\openerp\models.py", line 5883, in _onchange_eval
    self.update(self._convert_to_cache(method_res['value'], validate=False))
  File "C:\Users\zendynamix\odooGit\odoo8\openerp\models.py", line 5391, in _convert_to_cache
    for name, value in values.iteritems()
  File "C:\Users\zendynamix\odooGit\odoo8\openerp\models.py", line 5392, in <dictcomp>
    if name in fields
  File "C:\Users\zendynamix\odooGit\odoo8\openerp\fields.py", line 1250, in convert_to_cache
    return self.to_string(value)
  File "C:\Users\zendynamix\odooGit\odoo8\openerp\fields.py", line 1240, in to_string
    return value.strftime(DATE_FORMAT) if value else False
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to look at the underlying code sometimes to understand what's going on, you're getting errors because Odoo is trying to convert a boolean object back to a string representation of a time (it expects a python date object)

You can fire up a terminal and reproduce your error:

```
>>> True.strftime
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'strftime'
>>>
```

This is the `to_string` method from odoo

```
@staticmethod
def to_string(value):
    """ Convert a :class:`date` value into the format expected by the ORM. """
    return value.strftime(DATE_FORMAT) if value else False
```

The test condition if value test's to see if value evaluates to False, testing from the terminal

```
>>> x = ''
>>> if x: print('Yeah')
... 
>>> 
>>> x = True
>>> if x: print('Yeah')
... 
Yeah
>>> x = False
>>> if x: print('Yeah')
... 
>>> 
>>>
```

from the output, we can draw a conclusion that an empty string or `False` evaluates to False while a True value will evaluate to True, so instead of setting the date values to True, set all of them to empty strings.

```
@api.multi
def onchange_filter(self,filter='filter_no', fiscalyear_id=False):
    res = super(account_partner_ledger, self).onchange_filter(filter=filter, fiscalyear_id=fiscalyear_id)
    if filter in ['filter_no', 'unreconciled']:
        if filter == 'unreconciled':
            res['value'].update({'fiscalyear_id': False})
        res['value'].update({'initial_balance': False, 'period_from': False, 'period_to': False, 'date_from': False ,'date_to': False})

    if filter in ['filter_date','filter_period']:
        res['value'].update({'initial_balance': 'True', 'period_from': '', 'period_to': '', 'date_from': '', 'date_to': ''})

    return res
```

Comment: After changing it to blank,error has gone but 'include initial balance' checkbox is not getting checked by default

Comment: edit your question and include the module you're inheriting from

Comment: I have edited my question and module inherited is 'account.partner.ledger'

Comment: Oh i forgot to add, include the steps to get to the particular menu and view (e.g Account=>Reporting=>Legal Reporting)...i'm trying to reproduce the same steps

Comment: I have edited your answer and thats the working answer

Answer (score 1):

When you look at your code you'll see:

```
'date_from': True ,'date_to': True
```

This causes your error.
You should set those fields to a date not to a Boolean.
The value False is valid, since you should be able to not fill in a date.

Answer (score 0):

Try using strptime instead of strftime and see if it solves the problem.
You can use strptime as follows for example:-

`from openerp.tools import DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT
my_date = datetime.strptime(self.date_column, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)`